# Is there a way to repeat a try and except block in python? ( getting attribute error when target not found )

Tags: python, macos

I use the SIMBAD service a lot for looking up the coordinates of celestial objects. I thought I'd automate this using python. My first approach was using Selenium and having it run in Safari. However, this proved to be somewhat harder than doing it manually. About two days ago however I found out about astroquery and how it has SIMBAD built into it. So I thought I'd use that. It does work, but it keeps raising this Attribute Error and all of my attempts to fix it have resulted in a new bug. Here's the code: ( p.s I am using the astroquery library (( astroquery.simbad )) and a text formatter, rich ) :

```
from rich import print
from astroquery.simbad import Simbad


def ask_for(prompt, error_msg=None, _type=None):
    """ While the desired prompt is not given, it repeats the prompt. """
    while True:
        inp = input(prompt).strip()
        if not inp:
            if error_msg:
                print(error_msg)
            continue

        if _type:
            try:
                inp = _type(inp)
            except ValueError:
                if error_msg:
                    print(error_msg)
                continue
        return inp


def simbad_query():
    not_target = True
    while not_target:
        try:
            print(
                '\nTo find the [blue]RA and Dec[/blue] of your target, please put it in here.')
            print("If your target can't be found, it will automatically redirect you to the website to put it in again.")
            target = ask_for('\nTarget name: ')
            query = Simbad.query_object(f'{target}')
            query.pprint()
        except AttributeError:
            print(
                '\nThe target you gave was [red]not found[/red]. Please try again.')
            print(
                '\nTo find the [blue]RA and Dec[/blue] of your target, please put it in here.')
            print("If your target can't be found, it will automatically redirect you to the website to put it in again.")
            target = ask_for('\nTarget name: ')
            query = Simbad.query_object(f'{target}')
            query.pprint()
```

Comment: Sure there's a way, and you're doing it!  You just put the try/except block in a loop, just like you've done.

Comment: What `AttributeError` are you getting (which seems to have nothing to do with the question in the title)?

Comment: How do you run this script?

Comment: By calling the function? Also @Steve I am encountering a problem though. Whenever I get the target name wrong, it repeats it, but then when I do get it right it doesn't break out of the loop.

Comment: @chepner Sorry about that! I edited the title of the question to more accurately represent the probelm. Anyway, basically my problem is that I need to repeat this block of code if I can't find the target. The query.pprint() automatically raises an attribute error, so I thought I'd use try and except with a loop to do it. Problem is I can't break out of the loop. I've tried doing `else: not_target = False` but that doesn't allow me to get the target name wrong at all. Thus I can't reenter the target name and I'd have to go through the entier script again.

Comment: just a hint: `f'{target}'` is the same as `target`